# How to cast String float to Float in PySpark?

Tags: python, pyspark

I have the following PySpark dataframe:

```
df = spark.createDataFrame(
    [
        ('31,2', 'foo'),
        ('33,1', 'bar'),
    ],
    ['cost', 'label']
)
```

I need to cast the ´cost´ column to float. I do it as follows:

```
df = df.withColumn('cost', df.cost.cast('float'))
```

However, as I result I get `null` values instead of numbers in the `cost` column.

How can I convert `cost` to float numbers?

Comment: "," is not a valid char for the float.  you need to replace with "."

Comment: @Emma: Thanks, but how can I do it?

Comment: take a look at `regex_replace` function. https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.1.1/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.functions.regexp_replace.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work for you.

```
df = (df.withColumn('cost', F.regexp_replace(df.cost, ',', '.')
        .withColumn('cost', df.cost.cast('float')))
```

Comment: I'm not sure 'float will work'. Best to try DecimalType() form spark.sql.types

Answer (score 1):

I think a simple lambda expression should take care of most things.

```
    df.loc[:, 'cost'] = df.cost.apply(lambda x: float(x.replace(',', '.')))
```

Comment: Hmm, I use PySpark, not pandas. Is it also applicable to PySpark?

Comment: I haven't used PySpark in the past, but a quick glance at the description on Pypi.org shows that it makes use of numpy and Pandas, so I believe it's applicable. More importantly, have you tried the snippet I provided? Thanks!

Comment: Just for reference, I tend to avoid adding additional dependencies, so that's why my answer only uses what I know exists in the language itself.